# URL with JQuery Mobile

Tags: url, hyperlink, jquery-mobile

I am using JQuery mobile in asp.net web form website. I have the following code at the page "pageA.aspx".

```
  <a href="PageB.aspx.aspx" data-transition="fade" data-role="button"  data-icon="star">View Saved Orders</a>
```

When I am clicking on this link I am successfully redirected to the PageB, but the URL I am getting is

```
http://localhost:3244/MyFirstJQueryApp/PageA.aspx#PageB.aspx
```

But I want URL like this further processing, please help

```
http://localhost:3244/MyFirstJQueryApp/PageB.aspx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it by setting target="_top" property.

Is this a good practice ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of mods out there (can't find the one I wanted) to remove the hash in the URL, but you have to edit the jQM framework.

You could try using the changePage() http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/api/methods.html and set the transition without tracking it in history option to true (I think it's true)

Here is some more documentation on navigation as well: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/pages/docs-navmodel.html
 mightbe able to think of another way

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind jQuery Mobile is that you don't do it the way you're trying to do it!  Check [Dynamic pages with jQuery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844738/dynamic-pages-with-jquery-mobile), which shows you how to let jQm do the work in the background by loading new data into the DOM.